# With 1 Thread and 5 Iterations getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

Here is my test design

**Thread Group** : Normal Thread Group

**Thread Count** : 1

**Loop** : 5

**CSV Data file**  : Has 5 rows of data (Employee)

Execution Results: Creates 25 per Employee with different week ending Ex: emp1- 10-30-2021;emp1 -11-06-2021 like that 25 times. **For 26th getting the 403 forbidden.**

I am little confused here my expectation 5 different employees * with different weekending i.e emp1- 10-30-2021; emp2 -10-30-2021, On top of that i am getting 403 forbidden for 26th time. Even I am fine If i achieve from 26th emp2 generate 25 rows like that 5*25 =125. emp1 -25; emp2-25 .. emp5-25

Not sure what am i missing
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) and check which values are being sent for the 26th request.

If you're running test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) add a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and instruct it to save request and response data into XML file, when your test finishes open the .XML file in the View Results Tree listener and inspect the request body.

It might be the case you have an empty line at the end of your CSV file so it sends empty test data causing the request to fail (I would expect [status code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) though)

Comment: No it is not sending the empty line, if it is should the throws <EOF> Unauthorized. Token  value is passing properly there is no issue over there